# How to prove that a given polynomial $P(x)$ has no interger roots.

Tags: polynomials, roots

How to prove that a given polynomial $P(x)$ has no integer roots.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could add more details, like what polynomial are you dealing with, etc.

Comment: you probably mean a polinomial with integer coefficients?

Comment: thats right, polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: What about just finding them all.

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question please to make it more precise?

Comment: Note. There are as may r's in interger as there are in sherbert.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: coefficients are arbitrary but integer. so, factors of a0 are not known. Is there any other way ?

Comment: @Singh What do you mean? Once you have the polynomial, you can factor its coefficients.

Comment: You're right, the result doesn't work for arbitrary coefficients. As Mark Bennet said, you can prove that $\lim \limits_{\vert x \vert \rightarrow +\infty} \vert P(x) \vert = + \infty$ which means that, for every $A \in ]0,+\infty[$, there exists a $M \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $\left( \vert x \vert > M \right) \Rightarrow \left( \vert P(x) \vert \geq A > 0 \right)$. It means that $P(x) \neq 0$ for $\vert x \vert > M$. So you have to check all integers in $[-M,M]$, which can be done using a computer. The problem is then : given $A >0$, find such a $M$...

Comment: jibounet, what do you mean that it doesn't work for arbitrary coefficients? It seems to, as long as the constant term is not zero. And if the constant term *is* zero, then $0$ is an integer root.

Comment: I meant the theorem I was referring to in Wikipedia requires that the coefficients of the polynomial be integers (or rational).

Comment: Which is okay, because that's what's being asked here.

Answer (score 2):

With arbitrary coefficients (non-integers) the (non-zero) polynomial can be bounded away from the axis for large positive or negative $x$. Then you have a finite problem of checking the integers between.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few case, firstly, the easy case is when the polynomial is a constant, then there are either infinitely many, or none.

The second case is when we have a non-zero polynomial. $$a_nx^n+\dots+a_1x+a_0=0$$
where $a_n\neq0$. W.L.O.G, $a_0\neq0$ (just factorise $x$ so that $a_0\neq0$).

Then to see if there are integer roots, find the factorisation of $a_0$ and try solving the polynomial for each factor of $a_0$.

This works because the product of roots is $a_0$ up to sign.